# CM12 app install/reboot issue

Tags: cyanogenmod, moto-x

I've installed CyanogenMod 12.1 ([stable branch](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=ghost): `cm-12.1-20151117-SNAPSHOT-YOG7DAO1K9`) on my phone (MotoX, 1st gen) using Clockwork Recovery, including the version of [OpenGApps](http://opengapps.org/?api=5.1&variant=nano) recommended on [CM wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps), and [SuperSU](https://download.chainfire.eu/696/SuperSU/).  There are three issues i've noticed - putting them all here in case they're related...

1. App install from Play Store triggers soft reboot
2. `Android is upgrading, Starting apps` message on every boot
3. Can't copy files to device: `The device has either stopped responding or has been disconnected`

I've searched around but advice seems pretty thin.

UPDATE: I've checked `adb logcat` during install, and found that this seems to happen shortly prior to reboot:

`F/PackageManager( 5905): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Having checked for the file I can confirm it's not there. Is there a replacement I can add in order to resolve this? I've noticed that any new users created do have this file, though it doesn't seem possible to copy it across, even with root.

UPDATE2: Somehow i have files located in `/data/media/0/0/0/0/0/clockworkmod`: `.recovery_version` and `philz-touch_6.sav`

When I format in preparation for reinstall these files cannot be removed. I've also tried using root and adb shell to delete with no success. As a result apps seem to persist across OS reinstalls.

I think the best thing to try now is a manual reformat of the data partition...

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I used the version recommended on the [CM wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps): [OpenGApps](http://opengapps.org/?api=5.1&variant=nano).
[CGApps](https://github.com/cgapps/vendor_google/blob/builds/README.md) is also linked, so maybe worth trying that.
Is it ok to just install one over the other, or is there a method to remove it first?

Comment: @Izzy The [Open GApps FAQ](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/FAQ) says that only TWRP recovery is officially supported, though I had issues with it when flashing CM, so would prefer to stick with CWM.  I also found this in the details txt file: `APK contains a new Google certificate not yet available in the keystore, please contact Open GApps maintainer to get it included` - so maybe there's a key i need to install?

Comment: Haven't checked myself in a while (no longer using GApps), but as far as I've heard the packages do a removal first. If you want to be on the safe side, wipe and flash CM again before installing a different GApps package. Not sure about the certificate thing, but that might indeed be the cause of a crash (though not of a reboot).

Comment: I think it might be related to package-restrictions.xml (updated in question), but I've been unable to create a new one in that directory. If I create a new user everything seems to be in the right place though, so maybe a complete reset is the way to go.

Comment: That file missing shouldn't be the cause of a reboot. If it's not found, it should simply be created (see [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/48164/16575) and [here](http://www.madore.org/~david/linux/android.html#package-manager) for some background). Though I wonder why it was not created to start with, as it should include details of all packages (whether they're enabled/disabled, default app, etc.). I'd expect it to be created at the first startup automatically. Note that except from package manager, only root can access that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have all these issues resolved now.

Firstly I forced a format of my data partition, by flashing TWRP, switching the filesystem for `/data` to `ext4`, and then switching back to `f2fs`. This means that instead of just deleting files as it tends to do during a wipe it has to recreate the entire filesystem, removing those troublesome files from before in the process.

I then pushed CM12, OpenGApps and SuperSU zip files over adb to the data partition, before re-flashing CWM and installing them.

Boot into CM12 and everything works!

`.recovery_version` and `philz-touch_6.sav` have returned, this time to `/data/media/0/0/clockworkmod` but as I've already formatted by this point, they don't seem to be causing any problems.

Thanks to @Izzy and @Kshitij for their help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing this here because I am unable to comment.

- You could try a clean install i.e. wipe system, data, cache
  partitions and flash ROM & GApps packages.
- OpenGApps recommends that you flash OpenGApps package right after you
  flash the ROM without any reboots in between
  https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/Notes-for-Android-6.0 (I
  know this is for 6.0 but it might be applicable to previous versions
  as well)
- You could try posting your logs in the OpenGApps XDA Forum link given on
  their FAQ page
  https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/FAQ#2-im-having-a-problem-with-my-open-gapps-install-what-information-do-you-need-to-help-me

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input! I'm actually trying to do that at the moment, but the factory reset won't complete properly (fails to format `data`) due to the files mentioned in Update2 above.  I'm currently looking into manually formatting the partiton,  but so far have some up with little to nothing...