# Dolphin browser won't let me change default video player?

Tags: dolphin-browser

In Dolphin I had set "BPS player" to be the default video player when I selected the "Open in other apps" option in the dolphin Player. Now I want to change the default video player again but when I choose "Open in other apps" it just opens the BPS player! I tried to "clear defaults" on both apps but it didn't work. Do I have to uninstall Dolphin or BPS player? Help, searched all over google but didn't find anything.

Comment: What device, what android version? Possible duplicate of [Where does Android store the "default application for file type (open with)" settings?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34893/where-does-android-store-the-default-application-for-file-type-open-with-set)